# How to add areas inside of each city using php and woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I added new cities inside a country but I want to add **alot ** of areas inside of each of these cities.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_wc_states_eg' );

function custom_wc_states_eg ( $states ) {

    $states['EG'] = array(
    1=> "Alexandria",
        2=> "Assuit"
    );

return $states;
}
```

I tried writig this same code but with a new filter but I got errors on wordpress

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_areas', 'custom_wc_areas' );

function custom_wc_areas ( $areas) {

    $areas['Alexandria'] = array(
    1=> "Agami",
        2=> "more areas"
    );

return $areas;
}
```

Comment: There is no such function woocommerce_areas to start with. woocommerce_states is part of class WC_Countries so to extend it look this class first and build on it.